# How to route all document requests to Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller, servlet-filters, servlet-mapping

I'm building a Java web application with HTTP Servlets and I want to route all of the document requests to one Servlet class.

By document request, I mean that I don't want to have requests for images like favicon.ico going to my servlet, which is the case if I just use this mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What I'm doing is working pretty much like Symfony (the php framework) Controller layer. So I don't know what is the requested URI going to look like, I only know that it's going to follow this pattern: `/controller[/method]`. So I can't just use /action/* mapping for example.

I'm not looking for any Java MVC framework here since this is a school assignment, so I have to program it myself.

Comment: And what is wrong with `/action*`?

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know what the calling address is going to look like. Hence my reference to Symfony Controller layer. It's all dynamic. So you can use any combination that follows this pattern: /controller[/method]. But I admit, that I didn't wrote it clearly enough, I'll try to edit it a little.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's more of a workaround, but here is how I did it.

Apparently, I just had to change mapping to / instead of /*

I have all static content in /assets folder so it doesn't interfere with normal requests.

If there's an invalid request like /image.jpg (without /assets), My own code will route this to 404 Controller class, which seems to me like a valid behavior.